# how to call codes containing session variables globally in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to define codes globally in my asp.net  application.but my codes containing session variables.. where will i write those global function . please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the code in any assembly that has a reference to `System.Web.dll`. In your code access the session using

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]
```